# R: Finding duplicate sets of cells in a column

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

I'm looking for a way to detect duplicate sets of content.

So, for a set of *n* indices in a column (**V2**) (choosing *n* =3 to illustrate):

```
V1     V2
A      Hello
B      How are you
C      Fine
```

should match with:

```
V1     V2
D      Hello
E      How are you
F      Fine
```

but **not** with:

```
V1     V2
G      Hello
H      How are you
I      Crappy
```

Ideally, the return values I'm looking for should include:

1. For a chosen set length n, the contents of the cells that have duplicates and
2. The rownames or indices associated with the first element of each duplicate set

So, the first instance of a set of *at least* 3 cells whose contents and order have duplicates elsewhere in a dataframe:

```
V1     V2
A      Hello
B      How are you
C      Fine
```

along with the index or rowname of the first row containing a duplicate sequence:

```
V1
D
```

Comment: What would be the expected return values in both cases?

Comment: I've edited my post to include this information, thanks for reminding me to include it

Answer (score 0):

What kind of result are you expecting?

Is this helping?

```
 V1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
 V2 <- c("Hello", "How are you", "Fine")
 data_1 <- cbind(V1,V2)

 V1 <- c("D", "E", "F")
 V2 <- c("Hello", "How are you", "Fine")
 data_2 <- cbind(V1,V2)


 if (data_1[1,2] == data_2[1,2] & data_1[2,2] == data_2[2,2] & 
     data_1[3,2] == data_2[3,2]){
   TRUE
 }else{
   FALSE
 }
```